# use Promises in my code ?using deffered object and Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ember.js, promise

Hi I am using Jquery and ember to delete certain elements ,I want to use Deferred objects to stop the code and then next statements has to be executed

Here KillMany is Function once it is called it will execute  array.forEach(tryKill);
statement
that contains an array of elemets[array contains 100 elements inside for each each time a call back is calling to delete the each element from server]

Here I want to execute my code after completely finishing [deletion of elements] myFinalblock callback has to be calle

please guide me

```
    killMany: function(c) {
        var t = this
        ,   wait = []
        ,   dfd = new $.Deferred();

        function keep(tile) {
            tile.setProperties({ isSelected: false, isHidden: false });
        }

        function destroy(tile) {

            if (t.get('reports')) {
                t.get('reports').removeObject(tile.entity);
            }
            tile.remove.bind(tile);
        }

        function tryKill(tile) {
            tile.set('isHidden', true);
            tile.get('entity').kill()
                              .then(destroy.bind(null, tile),
                                    keep.bind(null, tile));
        }
         function myFinalblock(){
         this.set('selectedTiles', []);

          }
        this.set('promptDestroyMany', false);
        if (c.response) {
            var array = this.get('selectedTiles');
            array.forEach(tryKill);
            myFinalblock();

        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing the point of promises a bit. They do not "stop" your code. They allow you to cleanly route your code's asyncrhonous functionality. Therefore you need a way to wait until all of the `tryKill` calls are done before calling `myFinalBlock`. To do this, you first need to modify your `tryKill` function to return its promise:

```
function tryKill(tile) {
    tile.set('isHidden', true);
    return tile.get('entity')
               .kill()
               .then(destroy.bind(null, tile),
                     keep.bind(null, tile));
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
var tiles = this.get('selectedTiles');
$.when.apply($, tiles.map(tryKill))
      .then(myFinalBlock)
      .done();
```

On a side note, I suggest looking into a proper promise library and not using jQuery's built-in deferreds, as [they are known to have a number of problems](http://thewayofcode.wordpress.com/2013/01/22/javascript-promises-and-why-jquery-implementation-is-broken/).